# How to match a variable with value in double array

Tags: php, arrays

i have a problem like the following sample code :

```
$code='100'; //$maybe $code='0' or $code='1' ... i just set a number as an sample

$xx=array(
'0'=>array(a,b,c),
'1'=>array(d,e,f), 
........
'100'=>array(aa,bb,cc)
);
```

I want find $code in array :

```
if($code==$xx['$code']){
echo $xx['code'][0];  //if i want get the value 'aa'
}
```

But it seems like `$xx['$code']` doesn't work.
Do anyone know the right way to solve it?

Comment: echo $xx['$code'][0];

Comment: try echo $xx[$code][0];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly you need to use `array_key_exists` for getting within `if` condition and then after you can use it simply like as

```
if(array_key_exists($code,$xx)){
    echo $xx[$code][0];  
}
```

or can simply use `isset` instead like as

```
if(isset($xx[$code])){
    echo $xx[$code][0];  
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I got the answer i want.  Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

you shouldn't use single quotations here,
when filling displaying a variable either use without quotations or put it between double "" try `$xx[$code]` or `$xx["$code"]`

Answer (score 0):

Use [isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)  OR [!empty](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) to check key exist in array or not. It will also check that key has valid value.

```
  if(isset($xx[$code])){
      echo $xx[$code][0];  
  }
```

OR

```
  if(!empty($xx[$code])){
      echo $xx[$code][0];  
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if($code==$xx['$code']){
  echo $xx[$code][0];  //if i want get the value 'aa'
}
```

If you use `'$code'` the content of `$code` will not be checked as `''` interpret everything as a string and won't look a variables in it.

You can't sace `'code'` either, as `code` is only the name of the variable you use.